# How can i create an effective way for collision detection between rectangles in a dictionary in python, (using pygame to emmulate)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pygame

I know this question is long, but please help me your time will be greatly 
    appreciated, the question is not very complex compared to the writing, i am just 
    unsure of how to process, please help me . (You only need to read the code with 
    the dictionaries i was trying to link, the rest is just if you need it)

`I have been working tirelessly on this game which i am making for a project,` `it has all been running relatively smoothly until just recently i have found` `a rather large issue and i am not sure how to overcome it.`

My problem is as follows:

When i create a dictionary for an object which will do something on the screen`

(in this case the players' bullet):

I am able to place all of the dictionary objects on the screen and for it to do all of the necessary actions, such as move upwards, delete itself at a certain point and for it to display itself. Tho the problem occurs when i attempt to link some to eachother. For instance. I am able to correctly link my player's rectangle to the '`yummy`' dictionary, and if my player touches that rectangle then the `'score'` get's more points and the '`yummy`' is deleted. Same is true for when i try to have collision detection between the '`bullet`' and the bubble, it deletes the bubble, the bullet and gives more points which is what i desire. Though if i try to use this same method using `'z.colliderect(x,y)'` as used for the others, it does not work. If for instance i try to link my '`bigbullet`' and the '`yummy`' dictionaries rectangles to detect if the `'bigbullet'` has hit the '`yummy`' and to take action if this happens, i get a message saying:`

```
'File "E:\Bubble Dash\practice\bubbledashworking1.py", line 347, in play
    if u['rect'].colliderect(u['rect']):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'u' referenced before assignment'
```

I am really getting bummed out by this because i am not that great at 
programming  and i would really like to know how to make it so that my i cancontrol all of the dictionaries in the same way i have controlledthe `'bubble'` to '`bullet'` dictionaries where i can perhaps make the`'bigbullet'` delete and give me 40 score if it hits the '`bubble`'.

```
#Additional Information: ###########################################################
enemyImage = pygame.image.load('enemy2.png')

yummyImage = pygame.image.load('bubble.png')

bulletImage = pygame.image.load('Haduoken.png')

playerImage = pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerImage2 = pygame.image.load('sadplayer.png')
playerStretchedImage = pygame.transform.scale(playerImage, (40, 40))

def play(PLAY, playing, highscore):

    baddie = []
    yummy = []
    bullet = []
    bigbullet = []
    movex,movey = 0,0
    charx, chary= WindowWidth /2 - 20, 800
    enemyy, enemyx = 10, 10
    moveright = False
    moveleft = False
    spawn = False
    direction = 'down'

    score = 0
    level1min = 2
    level1max = 7
    level2min = 3
    level2max = 9
    level3min = 5
    level3max = 15
    level1 = False
    level2 = False
    level3 = False
    boom = False
    cheat = False

    #for i in range(20):
        #baddie.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WindowWidth - 40), random.randint(0, WindowHeight - 40), 40, 80))
    #enemycounter = 0
    #newenemy = 40
    while True: 
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('m'):
                    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                    music = False
                if event.key == ord('n'):
                    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                    music = True
                if event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveleft = True
                if event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveright = True
                if event.key == ord('w'):
                    movey = -5
                    if score > 100:
                        movey = -7
                    if score > 500:
                        movey = -10
                    if score > 1000:
                        movey = -12
                if event.key == ord('s'):
                    movey = 5
                    if score > 100:
                        movey = 7
                    if score > 500:
                        movey = 10
                    if score > 1000:
                        movey = 12
                if event.key == ord('p'):
                    time.sleep(5)

            if event.type ==KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveleft = False
                    if moveleft == False:
                        movex = 0
                if event.key == ord('c'):
                    cheat = True
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    cheat = False
                if event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveright = False
                    if moveright == False:
                        movex = 0
                if event.key == ord('w'):
                    movey = 0
                if event.key == ord('s'):
                    movey = 0
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        screen.blit(playscreenStretchImage,(0,0))
        player = pygame.Rect(charx, chary, 40, 40)  

        if direction == 'down':
            enemyy += 0.5
        if moveright ==True:
            movex = 5
            if score > 100:
                movex = 7
            if score > 500:
                movex = 10
            if score > 1000:
                movex = 12
        if moveleft ==True:
            movex = -5
            if score > 100:
                movex = -7
            if score > 500:
                movex = -10
            if score > 1000:
                movex = -12
        #for bad in baddie[:]:
            #if player.colliderect(bad):
               # print('COLLISION')

        if player.bottom > WindowHeight:
            chary = WindowHeight - 40
            movey = 0
            print'bottom'
        if player.top < 0:
            chary = 1
            movey = 0
            print'top'
        if player.left < 0:
            charx = -1
            movex = 0
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('d'):
                    movex = 5
            print 'left'
        if player.right > WindowWidth:
            charx = WindowWidth  - 39
            movex = 0
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('a'):
                    movex = -5
            print'right'

        if playing != False:
            score +=1
            score_render = font.render("score: %.0f"%score, True, (255,255,255))
            time_passed = clock.tick(60)
            time_passed_seconds = time_passed*1000

            if score in range(40, 60):
                screen.blit(countdown3, (WindowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2))
            if score in range(61, 80):
                screen.blit(countdown2, (WindowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2))
            if score in range(81, 100):
                screen.blit(countdown1, (WindowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2))
            if score in range(440, 460):
                screen.blit(countdown3, (WindowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2))
            if score in range(461, 480):
                screen.blit(countdown2, (WindowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2))
            if score in range(481, 500):
                screen.blit(countdown1, (WindowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2))
            if score in range(940, 960):
                screen.blit(countdown3, (WindowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2))
            if score in range(961, 980):
                screen.blit(countdown2, (WindowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2))
            if score in range(981, 1000):
                screen.blit(countdown1, (WindowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2))






            screen.blit(score_render, (0,0))
            if score > highscore:
                highscore = score
            finalscore = score
            score_render = font.render("%0.f"%score, True, (255,255,255))
            highscore_render = font.render("Highscore:%.0f"%highscore, True, (255,255,255))
            maxscore_render = font.render("%.0f"%highscore, True, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(highscore_render, (200,0))
#Here is the dictionaries i am trying to link:#########################################
            #BULLETS
            if len(bullet) <1:
                bulletSize = 30
                newBullet = {'rect': pygame.Rect(charx, chary, bulletSize, bulletSize),
                             'speed': -20,
                             'surface': pygame.transform.scale(bulletImage, (bulletSize, bulletSize))}
                bullet.append(newBullet)

            for l in bullet[:]:
                l['rect'].move_ip(0, l['speed'])
            for l in bullet[:]:
                if l['rect'].top < 0:
                    bullet.remove(l)
            for l in bullet[:]:
                screen.blit(l['surface'], l['rect'])

            #BIGBULLETS
                if len(bigbullet) < 1:
                    bigbulletSize = 200
                    newBigBullet = {'rect': pygame.Rect(0, WindowHeight - bigbulletSize, bigbulletSize, bigbulletSize),
                                    'speed': -5,
                                    'surface': pygame.transform.scale(bulletImage, (bigbulletSize,bigbulletSize))}
                if score in range(100, 200):
                    bigbullet.append(newBigBullet)
                for u in bigbullet[:]:
                    u['rect'].move_ip(0, u['speed'])
                    boom = False
                for u in bigbullet[:]:
                    screen.blit(u['surface'], u['rect'])



            #YUMMYYY
            if len(yummy)<5:
                if score < 100:
                    yummySize = 100
                    for y in yummy[:]:
                        if score == 100:
                            yummy.remove(y)
                if score > 100:

                    yummySize = 75
                    for y in yummy[:]:
                        if score == 500:
                            yummy.remove(y)
                if score >= 500:
                    yummySize = 50
                    for y in yummy[:]:
                        if score == 1000:
                            yummy.remove(y)
                if score >= 1000:
                    yummySize = 25




                newYummy = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WindowWidth - yummySize), random.randint(0, WindowHeight-yummySize), yummySize-yummySize/2.2 , yummySize-yummySize/2.2),
                            'speed': random.randint(eminspeed, emaxspeed),
                            'surface': pygame.transform.scale(yummyImage, (yummySize, yummySize)),}
                yummy.append(newYummy)

            for y in yummy[:]:
                y['rect'].move_ip(0, y['speed'])
            for y in yummy[:]:
                if y['rect'].top > WindowHeight:
                    yummy.remove(y)
            for y in yummy[:]:
                if player.colliderect(y['rect']):
                    yummy.remove(y)
                    score += 20
            for y in yummy[:]:
                if l['rect'].colliderect(y['rect']):
                    yummy.remove(y)
                    bullet.remove(l)
                    score +=40
##            for y in yummy[:]:
##                if u['rect'].colliderect(y['rect']):
##                    yummy.remove(y)
##                    score +=200
##           
            for y in yummy:
                screen.blit(y['surface'], y['rect'])

            #BADDDIESS
            if len(baddie)<30:
                eminsize = 10
                emaxsize = 40
                if score >= 900:
                    eminsize = 30
                    emaxsize = 60


                enemySize = random.randint(eminsize, emaxsize)
                newEnemy = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WindowWidth- enemySize),0-enemySize, enemySize, enemySize),
                            'speed': random.randint(eminspeed, emaxspeed),
                            'level1':random.randint(level1min, level1max),
                            'level2': random.randint(level2min, level2max),
                            'level3': random.randint(level3min, level3max),
                            'surface': pygame.transform.scale(enemyImage, (enemySize, enemySize)),}
                baddie.append(newEnemy)


            for b in baddie:
                if not level1 and not level2 and not level3 and not cheat:
                    b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['speed'])
                if score >= 100:
                    level1 = True
                    if level1 and not cheat == True:
                        b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['level1'])
                if cheat and level1 == True:
                    b['rect'].move_ip(0, 0)
                if score >= 500:
                    level1 = False
                    level2 = True
                    if level2 and not cheat == True:
                        b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['level2'])
                    elif cheat == True:
                        b['rect'].move_ip(0, 0)

                if cheat and level2 == True:
                    b['rect'].move_ip(0, 0)
                if score >= 1000:
                    level2 = False
                    level3 = True
                    if level3 and not cheat == True:
                        b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['level3'])

                if cheat and level3 == True:
                    b['rect'].move_ip(0, 0)
                if cheat == True:
                    b['rect'].move_ip(0,0)
            for b in baddie[:]:
                if level1 == True:
                    screen.blit(level1text, (400, 0))
                elif level2 == True:
                    screen.blit(level2text, (400, 0))
                elif level3 == True:
                    screen.blit(level3text, (400, 0))
            for b in baddie[:]:
                if b['rect'].top > WindowHeight:
                    baddie.remove(b)

            for b in baddie[:]:
                if player.colliderect(b['rect']):
                    baddie.remove(b)

                    charx, chary= WindowWidth /2 - 50, 340
                    playing = False

            for b in baddie:
#Additional Information:#############################################################
        while playing == False:

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == ord('m'):
                            pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                        if event.key == ord('n'):
                            pygame.mixer.music.play()
                        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                            pygame.quit()
                            sys.exit()
                        if event.key == ord('r'):
                            playing = True
                            play(PLAY, playing, highscore)
                        if event.key == ord('b'):
                            presskey(instrtomenu, highscore)
                    if event.type == QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

                    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        x, y = event.pos
                        if (x in range (28, 598)) and (y in range(570, 642)):
                            playing = True
                            play(PLAY, playing, highscore)
                        if (x in range (24, 712)) and (y in range(688, 760)):
                            presskey(instrtomenu, highscore)

                score += 0

                screen.blit(gameoverscreenStretchImage, (0,0))
                screen.blit(score_render, (494, 14))
                screen.blit(maxscore_render, (506 ,66))
                screen.blit(playerStretchedImage3, (0,227))

                if finalscore in range(1100, 1199):
                    screen.blit(gunterLabel, (450, 408))
                    screen.blit(gunterLabel2, (450, 463))
                    screen.blit(gunterStretchImage, (500, 519))
                pygame.display.update()
        screen.blit(playerStretchedImage, player)
        charx+=movex
        chary+=movey
        clock.tick(FPS)

        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: The problem is with the strings handling (for those who don't want to read the whole post)

Comment: why in the world are you using dictionaries instead of objects?

Comment: there is no such line in your code that prints this error.

Comment: Everything in one function - I give up. Create classes, functions, make mainloop shorter than came back with problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you may need a rather large overhaul in your program's structure. Dictionaries really will not do for this, you should be using classes, specifically sprites. This code is a sample of a sprite that includes a built in collision detector.

```
class collidable(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,coordinates,image):            #this method is called on an instance of a class upon creation. it is always nescessary to pass in "self" as the first argument to a def that is part of a class
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = coordinates
    def collide(self,other):                         #pass in the other sprite to check for a collision, this will return a True/False value of whether or not you are colliding with the other sprite
        mycollisions = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,other,False)
        for collision in mycollisions:
            if collision != self:
                return True
        return False
```

You may not know very much about classes and objects, and seeing as the topic is too broad for me to explain, I would recommend you check the python documentation on the subject, which is rather extensive. Here is the link: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Also, that may not make a lot of sense, so I shall attempt to introduce the basics. Python is an object oriented language. Just about everything in python is an object, including the numbers, strings, et cetera (when you add numbers, you actually call a def on the first number to add it to the other behind the scenes). A class is a specific type of object that users can use to make new objects. You can define a class and make multiple instances of it. A class contains a list of variables and functions inside of it, so that it will manage all the other objects regarding itself. This is necessary in pygame, because:

a: pygame provides a sprite class that does a lot of work for you, you should use it
b: classes are better ways to organize data, even if they seem confusing at first. the dictionaries you are currently using can serve a similar function, but classes are built to fill this position and do it much much better. Things such as moving entities on your screen need to manage certain things, such as location. Dictionaries can do that, but classes do it better.

After assigning attributes to a class, you may access them using

```
<classname>.<attributename>
```

for example, to call the collision function we made between two instances of the collidable class, we would do this:

```
mysprite = collidable((200,200),pygame.image.load("image_path.png").convert_alpha())
myothersprite = collidable((300,300),pygame.image.load("image_path.png").convert_alpha())
if mysprite.collide(myothersprite):
    print "sprites are colliding"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am inclined to agree with someone-or-other, you are more less coding in procedural and that is going to make things very difficult to debug as well as to write.

When I first started coding I wrote 30 page games in procedural and let me tell you, getting into using classes/functions will help you immensely.

At any rate, a very simple way to do collision detection is to just place a circle around your sprite and when the coordinance of object A are within the circle (use radius to determine this), then you set a trigger to that.

You can do it with squares also or even more complex shapes. In the case of a square for example, you just determine when the coordinance of object a is greater than the 'northwest' point of the containing square and smaller than the 'southeast' point.